# Facebook like button doesn't open in a new window

Tags: facebook, dom-events, facebook-like

I have a trouble with the facebook "i like" button. I put in my web site but I really need to open the Iframe in a new windows!
Is it possible?

If anyone has a tips please let me know; I going crazy with this, I couldn't find any hint online!

Comment: show us your code that you are using

Answer (score 1):

If anybody are still interest on this issue i discover in the facebook developer forum that you cannot open in a new window! Because the facebook team doesn't allow you.
My solution was to hide the comments iframe and just show the count. 
It's working good as well. Just the user can't give a title to the page that would like to share.